# Cannot Install Git Because Libc6 Package is Broken

Tags: debian, git

I am running debian 10 on the chrome os container.

I have attempted to install Git to the latest version however, I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.28-10 is to be installed
       Recommends: patch but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Libc6 shows that it is on version 2.28-10 when I run sudo apt install libc6.

I've tried to fix the broken packages and update the packages, but it still is showing the error. Thanks!

Edit: The output of `grep -Rn --include=\*.list ^[^\#] /etc/apt/` is as follows:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:2:deb https://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
/etc/apt/sources.list:3:deb https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cros.list:1:deb https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/88 buster main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3:deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ubuntu-ppa-hirsute.list:1:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu hirsute main
```

Comment: @GAD3R Completed

Answer (score 2):

You're using a PPA for Git for Ubuntu hirsuite, which is not the same as Debian buster.  Ubuntu hirsuite ships a newer version of libc6 and its version of the git package has been compiled against that version.

What you should definitely *not* do is attempt to upgrade libc6.  That will very likely break things.  Instead, if you want to use that PPA, use it for an older version of Ubuntu.  You could, for example, try focal or bionic.  That will probably provide a version compiled against an older version of libc6 and things will probably work.